# Configuring Xcode project to be built with specific build tools version

Tags: xcode, macos, xcodebuild, build-system

In my build system, I am using `xcodebuild` to build multiple projects.

I want to configure different Xcode installation to be used per project.

I know about `sudo xcode-select --switch <path>`, but:

- This option is system-wide, and might mess up with other parallel
  builds.
- It requires root, which I prefer to avoid (since it's an automatic build system).
- It is not configured internally in the project.

Is there a way to specify the build tools path to use per project?

Comment: You can probably launch `xcodebuild` directly from `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`

Comment: Thanks @NSDmitry, this actually works! It still isn't a project configuration, but I can live with that. Add the comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the output of `xcrun`:

> The active developer directory can be set using `xcode-select`, or via the DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable. See the xcrun and xcode-select manual
>   pages for more information.

E.g. to run xcodebuild with a specific Xcode-installation:

```
$ DEVELOPER_DIR=/path/to/my/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer xcodebuild
```

In a bash script:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=/path/to/my/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer

xcodebuild
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably launch `xcodebuild` directly from `Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`, so modifying the path you will use different Xcode version.

Comment: Thanks, I +1. Anyway I prefer @Mats answer for the official reference.